What does it refer to - a tree, color, or a tree falling?
Sometimes I can't get it right. What does it refer to in the passage?
Does it refer to just the preceding a tree, or color, or the act of a tree falling?

Most experts now agree that colour, as commonly understood, doesn’t
inhabit the physical world at all but exists in the eyes or minds of
its beholders. They argue that if a tree fell in a forest and no one
was there to see it, its leaves would be colourless – and so
would everything else. To put it another way: there is no such thing
as colour; there are only the people who perceive it.

The big idea: why colour is in the eye of the beholder

Pretty clear that "it" and "its" refers back to "a tree".

I would say that it refers to the event of the tree falling.

Note, this construction alters or extends a popular phrase used as a philosophical thought experiment about the nature of being and perception, "If a tree falls in a forest and no one is there to hear it, does it make a sound?"

"It" refers back to "tree", but from context the author is talking about a tree as it falls, so "The tree falling" would also be acceptable.
This is a case in which there is no ambiguity in terms of meaning, but there might be ambiguity in the exact interpretation of the anaphora.
But you can quickly move on. You will understand the same idea whether you understand  "it = tree (at the time of falling)" or "it = the event of the the tree falling".
